# images in django templates

Tags: django, python-2.7

Am parsing images and displaying it. As my wish I parsed. Am parsing news feed. In templates I want to check the condition that if images available means it will show the images otherwise it should show the image in static folder.
I need to check my syntax.

Template file:

```
{% for i in arr %} 
<img src="{% if image %}{{i.image}}{% else %}{<img src="/static/img/image.jpeg">}{% endif %}" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
{% endfor %}
```

The above is the code that I have written but the images are not displayed. 
Please guide me to proceed further

Comment: You probably meant `if i.image` there, not `if image`.

Comment: yes... also how to call the image file in static folder in else part. I have added all the steps needed to use media files. Am new to django

Comment: use `/{{ i.image.url }}` remember the `/` in front of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the following code that must solve your problem:

```
{% for i in arr %}
<img src="{% if i.image %}{{ i.image.url }}{% else %}{{ STATIC IMAGE URL }}{% endif %}" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: actually am a beginner... so I don't know how to give the static image. I have tried but didn't get the correct syntax. I have added a jpeg file in static folder. Could you please tell how to give static image url

Comment: The feeds with images are getting displayed.. I want the else part to work itseems

Comment: i got it... thanku                                                                <img src="{% if i.image %}{{i.image}}{% else %}{{STATIC_URL}}img/image.jpeg{% endif %}" style="width:100px;height:100px;">                                                      This is what actually I want.